# Displaying error like "insufficient storage" while installing in app is the property of the phone, or the app itself?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing an app for Android and iOS using cordova and it is almost in the last stages of its development. I am curious to know that how my app will react if the memory of the phone in which one is installing the app is insufficient. Will the phone prompt an error clearly saying that the memory is insufficient to install the app, or should I have to add some cordova plugin which will tell the user about the memory insufficiency of the phone ? 
For checking this I also tried filling my phone's memory with lots of app, and finally the google play store was giving the error of the insufficient storage even if I tried to install an app of the size approx 1MB, at that time my phone's remaining memory was around 37MB. And I tried installing my app which is not on Google Play Store yet, which is of size around 8MB, and it was installed successfully.

I am a bit confused, how the user will know the insufficient memory error. 
Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont need to handle that, Android handles it.

Comment: When I was trying to install the app of size approx 1Mb from Google Play Store, the play store was giving me the insufficient memory error. But, at the same point I tried to install my own .apk of size around 8MB, it was installed successfully. Why the play store denied to install the much lighter app than my own app ?

Comment: Maybe it dont install anything when you are below a minimum free space, its a good policy so you dont get out of space for a photo when some apps want to update and you are low on free space.